# WordPress.com podcast feed missing iTunes tags?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, podcasting

I recently published [a podcast](http://cocos2dpodcast.wordpress.com/) hosted on WordPress.com [on iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/be/podcast/cocos2d-podcast/id430336625) and it says "Podcasts by Unknown". It seems like it is missing the author tag. My question is that how can I add the author tag to the RSS since I used the RSS widget to expose my RSS?

Comment: Are you talking about the [HighOnCoding podcast](http://itunes.apple.com/be/podcast/highoncoding/id322689441)? Because I see "By Mohammad Azam" in the description. Where do you see this "Unknown"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually, I am talking about http://cocos2dpodcast.wordpress.com/. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes [uses extra tags](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html) for author information, category classification, ... I believe [you can't add these using WordPress.com](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/podcast-feed-for-itunes-in-wordpresscom). What you can do is pick up your feed using FeedBurner and submit that URL to iTunes instead. FeedBurner has support for podcasts and allows you to fill in the extra iTunes tags.

Comment: To resubmit the podcast to iTunes with Feedburner URL I will need to delete the original podcast from iTunes. Will Apple allow me to add the same podcast again once it has been deleted!

Comment: @azamsharp: I don't know, maybe you can ask this on [the Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)?